# Obtener un valor de una función

Tags: javascript

Como puedo obtener el valor de la variable subtotal fuera de la siguiente función, sin que dicha variable se declare fuera?

```
   function updateSubtotal(product) {
    
  let price = product.querySelector(".price span").innerHTML
  let quantity = product.querySelector(".quantity").value
  let subTotal = price * quantity
  document.querySelector(".subtotal").innerHTML=subTotal
 
}
```

Comment: pues con un return subTotal, ej console.log(updateSubtotal("producto")) o tambien let miTotal = updateSubtotal("producto")

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un `return` en la función y almacenar ese valor en dónde quieras para usarlo como andes pensando.

```
 function updateSubtotal(product) {
   
  let price = product.querySelector(".price span").innerHTML
  let quantity = product.querySelector(".quantity").value
  let subTotal = price * quantity
  document.querySelector(".subtotal").innerHTML=subTotal
 
return subTotal; 

}
```

Podrías almacenarla de la siguiente forma:

```
let subTotal = updateSubtotal(producto);
```